# Android - what kind of view/xml I've to study

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

**Problem** I want view-layout like the following photo, on top I want image view, in the middle a text view and bottom list of items. All this I want to be scrollable (black arrow in the picture). in this way, the user for first see image-text-and part of list items, if scroll down, see the list of item.
For the bottom I thought to use listView, but in this way I think I'll have 2 scrollable view (???) and then I want to make the list in 2 columns, and I don't know if it is possible with ListView

[image]

**Question**

I didn't write code, because I want to know what kind of view or somethings else I've to study.
I sketchy something like this, but the result is really horrible

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nope"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/centerShim5"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textColor="@color/ame_default_cluster_circle_color_medium"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Of course listview can have two columns. You can make your adapter display whatever you want in each row

Comment: Your current problem is that you have all the views in the ScrollView, not only the TextView

Answer (score 0):

I can't use listview in Scrollview, and inspired by the matryoshka I found the solution.
I define  xml1 file in which I have only ScrollView and LinearLayout inside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linear">



    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

after, for each kind of items that I want to add inside, I define another xml2 and after I add element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ame_default_cluster_text_color">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="@color/ame_default_cluster_circle_shadow_color"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/nope"
        android:id="@+id/photo" />

    <TextView
        android:text=" "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/descrtiption"
        android:textColor="@color/ame_default_cluster_circle_shadow_color"
        android:layout_margin="10sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

with code:

```
layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View item_view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.xml1,container,false);
            LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)item_view.findViewById(R.id.linear);
            LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
            View view1  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml2, linearLayout, false);
            TextView text1=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text1.setText();
            ImageView imageview=(ImageView)view1.findViewById(R.id.photo);
```

and obviously I can define XML for element to add like listview and add it with normal `foreach` ,Hope this will help someone.